# Spring with Thymeleaf binding date in html form

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a simple snippet of form like:

```
<form th:action="@{'/save'}" th:object="${account}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="expirationDate">Expiration date</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="expirationDate"
               placeholder="Expiration date" th:field="*{expirationTime}"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm passing there a filled object `account` and `expirationTime` is a `LocalDateTime` field. The problem is that the `expirationTime` is not bind with the value passed to the form (object which is passed is 100% correct). 
Any idea why?

Answer (score 13):

**Edit:** Simply put, Spring/Thymeleaf doesn't format a Java 8 date correctly for the datetime-local input type.  Tell Spring how to format the value correctly with @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm").

---

The annotation @DateTimeFormat tells Thymeleaf how to format the date string when parsing/formatting. That includes producing the value= annotation in the HTML input, and reading in POST data submitted by the form. The datetime-local input type expects a value formatted yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm, so we use that as the formatter in the model class.

### Model Class:

```
public class DateContainer {

    private String name;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/dateTest")
public String dateTest(final DateContainer dateContainer) {
    if (dateContainer.getDateTime() == null) {
        dateContainer.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
    return "dateTest";
}
```

### Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/dateTest}" th:object="${dateContainer}">
        <label>Name: </label><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <label>Date Time: </label><input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{dateTime}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### HTML Produced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <form action="/dateTest">
        <label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
        <label>Date Time: </label><input type="datetime-local" id="dateTime" name="dateTime" value="2017-08-28T13:01" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="437b30dc-a103-44d0-b4e9-791d8de62986" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Screenshot:

[Screenshot in Chrome 60](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmhIq.png)

### Comptibility:

The datetime-local input type is a new HTML5 type and isn't supported in all browsers.  See compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#search=datetime-local

In non-compliant browsers, the datetime-local field will simply appear as a text field, and will contain the date and time with the T in between.  That may lead to usability issues depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After that just add the org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.dialect.Java8TimeDialect class to the list of dialects in your TemplateEngine implementation, and you will have the #temporals object available to be used in your templates.
More details can be found [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time).

Comment: I'm using spring boot, how add the dialect by simply creating new bean for template engine ?

Comment: Try create a bean: @Bean public Java8TimeDialect java8TimeDialect() {
     return new Java8TimeDialect();
}

Comment: There's no changes.

Comment: Did you chage this line th:field="*{expirationTime}" on th:field="${#temporals.format(expirationTime)}" ?

Comment: Then I receive an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '#temporals'